# Möbius strip zero curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Is there a Möbius strip, seen as an embedded surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with zero curvature? I know one can see the Möbius strip as the quotient of the square with reverse identification of two sides but I want something with induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^3$. In other words, can I construct a Möbius strip, as an embedded surface, s.t. it is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$? If it is possible, what does such a parametrization look like?

Comment: see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0946.pdf.

Comment: Heuristically, the Mobius bands you can make out of strip of paper should be flat.  Of course this isn't quite rigorous as there may be small folds.

Comment: This is a typical undergraduate homework problem.  I have voted to close.

Comment: Wow, this is not a homework problem that I would have been able to solve as an undergraduate. Here's another reference on the topic: [Möbius bands, unstretchable material sheets and developable surfaces](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.2016.0459), by Yi-chao Chen and Eliot Fried.

Comment: In English one says "what does it look like?" or "how does it look?", but not "how does it look like?". And "how does it look?" is often construed as "how good does it look?" So you probably should say "what does it look like?"

Comment: The paper to which Igor Belegradek links refers to $\text{“} (-1,1)/\sim_\varphi \text{”},$ where it ought instead to say $\text{“} (-1,1)/{\sim_\varphi} \text{”}.$ I wonder why more than $95\%$ of mathematicians are so spelling-challenged and miss obvious things like this?